# Ripped off connector with no trace left

Tags: connector, identification

My friend's phone (ZTE F101) had the miniUSB connector ripped of the board, and when it broke it also pulled the pad. All 5 pads of the connector don't have traces and instead they have micro-vias right in the middle to the inner layers.
We don't care about the USB connectivity, but without the connector the phone can't be recharged, so we are trying to restore the GND and the +5V pins of the connector ignoring D+ and D-. The ground connection was easy to restore by simply connecting it to the ground plane available everywhere, but can't figure out where to connect the +5V.

I found an interesting spot on the other side of the board (relative to the miniUSB connector) where there is a big cap with one end connected to ground, and the other connected to a possibly SOT23-3 diode (marked with "S 5") as seen in the second picture, which made me believe that's where all the juice goes. So I connected to that cap, my little jumper wire connected to the +5V from the miniUSB connector, but it didn't work. The phone does not indicate that is charging the battery.

Does anyone have any idea what else to try, or recognize any voltage regulators in the picture?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things I can advise in this are as follows:

1. Try to see if the original micro-via still contains sufficient metallisation to measure with a multimeter.
2. Find a place where the resistance to that micro-via is as good as zero.
3. Test with a lab supply by touching the micro via with +5V while measuring the voltage on that pad (if it's not a mentionable drop, it might work).

Noting that:

- Maybe you can still solder to the micro-via, although its connection to the inner layer may be damaged and create a higher than advisable resistance.
- Usually the +5V goes directly to a power management chip with passives surrounding it (coils and caps) to control both charge and the power flow to the electronics.
- You may have already broken something by willy-nilly forcing 5V on some part that may have been meant to create a low-drop 1.8V, or even lower.

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried, but I can't find those microvias, they are too thin for my probes.

Comment: @Chris If you can't access the original entry point and have no datasheets for the devices involved in the power path you're out of luck with multilayer designs.

Comment: I know, this is why we are willing to risk anything. We don't care if the thing fries, but we want to try and fix it. The big cap that we tried has one end to ground and it's situated right underneath the connector, that's why we had such confidence. What we ask is if people can identify any block/package that would help us discover the V+ rail, or if they know how the voltage step down is usually done in mobile phones.

Comment: Wow .. I just tried again to find the microvias with a powerful magnifier, and I did found one on the +5V pad.I did a bit of jiggle around and apparently those 6 test points in front of the miniUSB connector are equivalent to the connector's pads. After a bit of research I've fond that the power management is done by the Qualcomm chip and the USB VDD is connected directly to the BGA chip. The cap I was mocking around with 5V on, is connected at the battery, so fortunately I didn't damage anything, except a short high current burst in the battery :D

Comment: That's very lucky, usually those small "regulator type things" create a specific low drift voltage for some peripheral, for which the cap would then likely be output stabiliser.